# Time Series Forecasting Using Deep Learning in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, time-series, lstm

I am using the time series forecasting sample from MathWorks in https://uk.mathworks.com/help/nnet/examples/time-series-forecasting-using-deep-learning.html

The output in the above-mentioned web-address is:

[image]

I only changed the dataset and ran the algorithm. Surprisingly, the algorithm is not working good with my dataset and generates a line as forecast as follows:

[image]

I am really confused and I cannot understand the reason behind that. I might be need to tune parameters in the algorithm that I am not aware on that. The code I am using is:

```
%% Load Data
%data = chickenpox_dataset;
%data = [data{:}];

data = xlsread('data.xlsx');
data = data';

%% Divide Data: Training and Testing
numTimeStepsTrain = floor(0.7*numel(data));
XTrain = data(1:numTimeStepsTrain);
YTrain = data(2:numTimeStepsTrain+1);
XTest = data(numTimeStepsTrain+1:end-1);
YTest = data(numTimeStepsTrain+2:end);

%% Standardize Data
mu = mean(XTrain);
sig = std(XTrain);

XTrain = (XTrain - mu) / sig;
YTrain = (YTrain - mu) / sig;
XTest = (XTest - mu) / sig;

%% Define LSTM Network
inputSize = 1;
numResponses = 1;
numHiddenUnits = 500;

layers = [ ...
    sequenceInputLayer(inputSize)
    lstmLayer(numHiddenUnits)
    fullyConnectedLayer(numResponses)
    regressionLayer];

%% Training Options
opts = trainingOptions('adam', ...
    'MaxEpochs',500, ...
    'GradientThreshold',1, ...
    'InitialLearnRate',0.005, ...
    'LearnRateSchedule','piecewise', ...
    'LearnRateDropPeriod',125, ...
    'LearnRateDropFactor',0.2, ...
    'Verbose',0, ...
    'Plots','training-progress');

%% Train Network
net = trainNetwork(XTrain,YTrain,layers,opts);

%% Forecast Future Time Steps
net = predictAndUpdateState(net,XTrain);
[net,YPred] = predictAndUpdateState(net,YTrain(end));

numTimeStepsTest = numel(XTest);
for i = 2:numTimeStepsTest
    [net,YPred(1,i)] = predictAndUpdateState(net,YPred(i-1));
end

%% Unstandardize the predictions using mu and sig calculated earlier.
YPred = sig*YPred + mu;

%% RMSE and MAE Calculation
rmse = sqrt(mean((YPred-YTest).^2))
MAE = mae(YPred-YTest)

%% Plot results
figure
plot(data(1:numTimeStepsTrain))
hold on
idx = numTimeStepsTrain:(numTimeStepsTrain+numTimeStepsTest);
plot(idx,[data(numTimeStepsTrain) YPred],'.-')
hold off
xlabel("Month")
ylabel("Cases")
title("Forecast")
legend(["Observed" "Forecast"])

%% Compare the forecasted values with the test data
figure
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(YTest)
hold on
plot(YPred,'.-')
hold off
legend(["Observed" "Forecast"])
ylabel("Cases")
title("Forecast")

subplot(2,1,2)
stem(YPred - YTest)
xlabel("Month")
ylabel("Error")
title("RMSE = " + rmse)
```

And the `data.xlsx` is in: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vv1apug7iqlocu1/data.xlsx?dl=1

Answer (score -2):

You want to find temporal patterns in the data. Matlab's data looks like a sine-wave with noise, a very clear pattern. Your data is far from showing a clear pattern. Your data needs preprocessing. I would start by removing the slow drifts. A high-pass, or band-pass filter of some sort makes sense. Here is a simple line just for a quick view of your data without the slow frequencies:

```
T=readtable('data.xlsx','readvariablenames',0);
figure; plot(T.Var1-smoothdata(T.Var1,'movmean',200))
```

Comment: Tnx. I agree with you. But if I smooth my data, I cannot predict next time-interval accurately, and I will face with high prediction error. Am I right?

Comment: Or better to say, the predicted value is also smoothed value, How can I convert it into a real value? Because, I need a real value.

Comment: You cannot predict these mountains you have there, they have no pattern. If you train your net on high-pass filtered data you have a chance for find patterns on smaller scale. If you find such patterns, you have to add them to baseline / DC. For example, you take the last real sample and add to it the predicted value.

Comment: Tnx. With your suggested `movmean, 200`, it provides the same results, I mean the one line as predictor!. I think that I need to find a good value for `movmean`.